# aws_security_group - conditional ingress

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terragrunt

I'm testing Terraform/Terragrunt to deploy RDS DB to AWS.

Is there a way to add conditional `ingress` to the `aws_security_group` definitions?

Terraform v0.12.3
Terragrunt version v0.19.8

As now the best I was able to do was add one security group for each condition, each with a count statement, and add all the single security groups to the DB instance,  like

```
resource "aws_security_group" "db_sg_office" {
      ...
      count = var.publicly_accessible ? 1 : 0
      
      ingress {
        ...
        cidr_blocks = ["1.2.3.4/32"]
      }    
}

...
    
resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  ...
  vpc_security_group_ids = [ ... , "${aws_security_group.db_sg_office.id}" , ...]
  ...
}
```

This is actually NOT working and fails when the security group is referenced in the DB resource.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On terraform try to use `aws_security_group_rule` resource with **count** parameter, for additional reference read [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule)

```tf
resource "aws_security_group" "db_sg_office" {
  ...
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "open_public" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.db_sg_office.id
  count     = var.publicly_accessible ? 1 : 0
  type      = "ingress"
  from_port = 0
  to_port   = 65535
  cidr_blocks = ["1.2.3.4/32"]
  protocol  = "tcp"
}
```